# IE11 Not recognizing the content declaration for Font Awesome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I am using Font Awesome 4.4.0 and noticed that icons only show in IE11 when I use HTML such as . However, IE11 does not recognize the "content" declaration in the Font Awesome CSS. An example of such a class is:

```
hr.code-light:after,
hr.code-primary:after {
    content: "\f121";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -.8em;
    padding: 0 .25em;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

When I apply the code-light or code-primary class to the HR tag, no Font Awesome icon appears. In IE11, Font Awesome icons only appear when I specify it in the HTML.

Anyone know a fix or workaround to this issue?